# IntelliJ IDEA 2019 + lombok + LibGDX. How to fix failed build of application using gradle runner

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx, lombok

I'm trying to run (or build jar) application using LibGDX, lombok, log4j2 via gradle runner, but it always failed. Looks like lombok dependency is absent in project. Could someone help me to uderstand what I'm doind wrong?

So, there are repro steps:

1. Create LibGDX project using instruction https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA. Runner that used for compiling is gradle.

**Result:**
After this step application is built successfully. All places works fine.

2. Added couple of dependecies (multiproject):

```
project(":shared") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"

    dependencies {
        api "com.google.inject:guice:4.2.2"
        api "com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assistedinject:4.2.2"

        api "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10
        annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10"

        api "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.12.1"
        api "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.12.1"
    }
}
```

**Result:** Any attempt to run or build application failed with errors:

```
error: cannot find symbol log.info (...)
```

or

```
error: cannot find symbol @RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
```

etc.

**Environment and soft**

I'm using Linux Mint 18.3, Intellij IDEA 2019.1. Annotation processor enabled, lombok plugin installed, gradle 5.4.1, java 8.

Also one thing. If I ran application via default runner (Intellij IDEA), all works fine.

I absolutely don't understand what wrong. If someone could help me, it will be cool.

Comment: Please, check for other lombok versions in other projects on the second step, In gradle file and in the classpath (+ external libraries if use IDEa). For me, there was different version of lombok. After I left a single version of lombok, everythin was fine

Comment: @mzherdev Thanks for your answer. I have found root cause. It was wrong classpath. Thank you.